# Remove Network Printer with Powershell Fail

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, group-policy, printer

I did a powershell script that remove network printer. It is run with a scheduled deployed by GPP in user preferences that runs at any session logon.

Here is the script. It does search for printer with a network hostaddress that does equal the var $port but does not have the name of the var $imprimante The script does look for printer with TCP/IP port and WSD port

```
get-date > C:\Temp\debug.txt
###Variables###
$imprimante = "001 - HP LaserJet Pro M400 color M451dn (Salle prof)"
$port = "10.26.57.21"
###End###

Write-Host "Start Standard TCP/IP Printer"
Get-WmiObject win32_tcpipprinterport | select name, hostaddress | %{    
    $printer = New-Object System.Object
    $printer | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $_.name -PassThru | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name HostAddress -Value $_.HostAddress
    if ($printer.hostaddress -like $port)
    {

        $name = $printer.name    
        $p = Get-WmiObject win32_Printer -Filter "PortName like '$name' and not (Name like '$imprimante')"
        $count = $p | measure
        if ($count.count -gt 0)
        {
            $pn = $p | Select property -ExpandProperty Name
            Write-Host "The printer '$pn' is going to be removed."
            $p.delete()
        }        
    }    
}

Write-Host "End Of Standard TCP/IP Printer"

Write-Host "Start Of WSD Printer"

Get-WmiObject win32_Printer -filter "PortName like 'wsd%'" | %{
    $p = $_
    $pn = $_.name
    $pc = $pn | measure
    if ($pc.count -gt 0)
    { 
        $address = (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\$pn\PrinterDriverData\ -Name HPEWSIPAddress).HPEWSIPAddress
        if ($address -like "$port*" -and $pn -notlike "$imprimante")
        {          
           Write-Host "The printer '$pn' is going to be removed."
           $p.delete()
        }              
    }   
}

Write-Host "End Of WSD Printer"
```

So far, the script runs well, the Scheduled Task also runs, but there is a persistent problem. The last printer to be deleted (or the printer if there is only one) does still shows up in "devides and printers".

The printer seems to be "uninstalled" because it is no more usable.
Here is a picture before the script (Sorry french environnement)[Printer before remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2pc8.png)

Here is a picture after the script[Printer after remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72tqn.png)

All options about printing is gone but the printer still remain. The only to get rid of it is to delete it manually.

Anyone have has ever seen this? I've tryed to remove the printer with "Rundll printui.dll" and did not succeed.

Thanks alot

Comment: What happens if you restart the spooler service after the script?

Comment: Nothing, I tried to stop it before and start it after the script it does nothing more.

Comment: Stop  _Print Spooler_ service. Then, check `C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS`. If there is any files in here they are corrupted print jobs. Delete them and start _Print Spooler_ service.